# Access violation when using QT objects in my program

Tags: c++, qt, dll, static-libraries, msvc12

I want to **integrate QT** into an existing desktop C++ project. The requirements were that **QT should be statically built with MSVC2013 64bit** and with **/MT flag** set for compiler, so I built **QT5.5.0** from sources.

The integration worked as expected, I managed to test some of Qt's object(QFile, QObject) from QtCore.lib. The application seems to run without any problems, without crashing. However, the program exists with `-1073741819` error level.  I attached the debugger and tried to catch the exception in Visual Studio and I got the following:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007FFAC6E4E1A2 in silversim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00007FFAC6E4E1A2.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAC6E4E1A2 in silversim.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00007FFAC6E4E1A2.
```

I undo the code integration until I had just a simple `QObject object;` declaration inside a function. With this simple declaration the program exists with error, **without any use of Qt objects the program exists normally**.

What is happening here? Might be the static link to Qt? Maybe a bug in the Qt5.5 versions? Or something else from my program trying to deal qt .libs somehow during cleanup?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to IDA decompiler I managed to find out where the crash happens but still I don't know why. It crashes in `void __fastcall qt_watch_adopted_thread(HANDLE hObject, struct QThread *)`. As I noticed, Qt creates some threads which are not destroyed when the program exits, and those threads try to access invalid memory. Maybe it is related with this opened qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40247 but in my case I'm not loading any plugin.

Comment: Can you show some code? Why are you using such an ancient Qt version?

Comment: There is a lot of code to show but I don't think it's relevant., because it is an old, well tested C++ code. A simple declaration of a Qt object anywhere in any function is enough to produce the error exit code. (also see the update)

Comment: blind guess: Qt's classes are supposed to be used within a QApplication. So you should probably create a Q(Core)Application object in your main() before doing anything else.

Comment: @markus-nm good hint. I'll try and let you know if it worked